# Spring Batch Listener defined with @Component not being found

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We have multiple jobs that all use a similar pattern.

Class file for `MyJobListener` is defined with `@Component` annotation.

Listener in XML is defined:

```
<batch:listeners>
   <batch:listener ref="myJobListener" />
</batch:listeners>
```

Seems to work just fine in some cases but not for others.  In some cases, we are getting an error:

```
ERROR (CommandLineJobRunner.java:355) - Job Terminated in error: Failed to load bean class: mypackage.myJobListener; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [mypackage/myJobListener.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Not certain why it is doing this (the jobs are all coded the same way).

**UPDATE**

This seems to be an environment issue. The Spring Batch jobs run perfectly fine in one environment, but we are in the process of updating to a new server. On the new server, all of our jobs are getting the error (FileNotFoundException).

*Please let me know what other information may be needed.*

***OLD SERVER***

---

java version "1.6.0_43"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)

Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)

Machine hardware:   sun4u

SunOS version:         5.10

Processor type:     sparc

Hardware:           SUNW,Sun-Fire-480R

***NEW SERVER***

---

java version "1.6.0_43"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)

Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)

Machine hardware: sun4v

SunOS Version: 5.10

Processor type: sparc

Hardware: sparc SUNW,T5240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to come out here and notify everyone of the resolution.

Looks like the issue had to do with a corrupted jar file.

We ran `jar -tf` on all of the project jar files. For one of the jar files, it recieved an error:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
```

Redploying the jar file seemed to take care of the issue.

Not certain why the jar file had issues. We use ANT to build the jar files, and then combine them into a tar file for deployment. We SFTP the tar file to the unix server, and then untar it. For some reason, the jar files sometimes are having issues, but redeploying seemes to clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your config...

Make sure you define your class like this:

```
@Component("myJobListener")
public class MyJobListener implements JobExecutionListener{
```

And make sure you have something like this somewhere in your ApplicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage" />
```

to load your annotated beans (your listeners)

Comment: We do have the context setting in our job definition, but I did try updating it to be more explicit to no avail.  The real issue seems to be with where the code is running.  I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Mmm... can you check if your class is really in your JAR file.  Note: Java convention tell you to name your class with a capital letter.  myJobListener.class should be MyJobListener.class...  i doubt this could be the problem.. but it might be!

Comment: The class is in the jar and does begin with a capital letter, that was just a typing error converting the real name to something generic.

Comment: Ok, can you add some debug log with a log4j Logger on org.springframwork.beans to see what beans are loaded by Spring.  Try to see if your "myJobListener" is listed.  From the error message, it is definitely a class-path issue...

Comment: It seems to be loading everything correctly, even other classes in the same jar. And I did validate that the class does exist inside of the jar.